# Upgrade outdated PHP Modules

Tags: linux, opensuse, php

If I execute `php -i` then I get this at the top:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20170718
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
```

How can I upgrade the php extension / module?

I installed a new PHP version from source, but the warning is still there.

Do I have to include a special option in `configure`?

This is what I have used: `./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/cli --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/cli`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i can't comment yet,

Probably use the `pecl` command, to re-download the sources of the extensions in question, and re-compile them?

There's all the doc https://pecl.php.net/

Then you could try

```
pecl upgrade-all
```

or

```
pecl uninstall module_name
```

and then

```
pecl install module_name
```

If those does not work to... sadly i can't help...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never used `pecl` before. Not sure how it works.

Comment: Does not work. I get `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/curl"` after calling `pecl install curl`

Comment: I tried `pecl upgrade-all` but I get `Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105` so I uncommented  `extension=openssl` in php.ini but I get `PHP Startup: openssl: Unable to initialize module`